# Why Java applet works on windows but not on Mac 10.6.8?

Tags: java, macos, applet, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using webmin, in which I want to use the plugin called "File Manager".
It's based on Java Applet and it perfectly works with Internet Explore on windows XP.

But with Safari on MacOSX 10.6.8 it says "inactive plug-in", and won't show anything.
If I click on it, MacOSX starts to check if there's new update.
However there is no update.

I spent time on researching on this.  Then I found this.

> Go to java preference => click enable applet plugin and web start application.

It was already enabled...

I have no idea what I can do.  I used to be able to use this "File Manager" until yesterday.

Comment: Have you installed java on your mac?

Comment: I'd expect it has to do with the recent vulnerability, particularly if you say it was working, e.g., http://www.macrumors.com/2013/01/11/apple-blocks-java-7-on-os-x-to-address-widespread-security-threat/

Comment: @alnasfire no. Do I need to? It was working until yesterday:(

Comment: @DaveNewton What can I do if I want to use it back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the same problem with 10.6

Found [this](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/01/).

I personally changed the version in that `XProtect.meta.plist` to `434` instead of `435` and this re-enabled the plugin.